# Kivy: How to change a widget's background color at runtime?

Tags: python, colors, widget, kivy

I want to create rows of widgets that contains different column widgets, some of those are textLabels. What I want to do is to be able to change the background color of a row during runtime. To do this I use horizontal box layouts as rows. Is it possible to change the background color of this layouts during runtime?

All the solutions I've found are to change the background color at the moment they are created but doesn't work during runtime.

```
kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint_y=None)
```

This are the widgets I am currently working with but I am open to use another type of widget for this.

Some widgets inside the layout block the layout's background, those doesn't have to change color but it wouldn't matter either way, I am interested in changing the background in all the textLabels from a row at least.

Comment: There's basically no barrier to this, whatever you've understood that you can do during creation can also be done at any other time. Can you give more detail about exactly where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `textLabel` (I assume you mean `Label`). You can easily modify the background color of a `Label` by defining a custom `Label`, let's call it `MyLabel` as:

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    rgba = ListProperty([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]) # will be used as background color
```

This defines a `rgba` property of `MyLabel` that can be referenced in a `kv` file as:

```
<MyLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.rgba
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Then the background color of an instance of `MyLabel` (call it `mylab`) can be changed with:

```
mylab.rgba = [1, 0, 0, 1] # or any other rgba
```

If you want to change the background color of a row of `MyLabel` widgets, just do the above in a loop.